# Cannot load Windows XP after deleting ubunutu partition

Tags: grubrescue, boot-partition

I would first like to point out that I am extremely new to running different operating systems (dual booting etc.) and Linux in general but after having continous issues with XP, trying Linux i considered was a viable
Option. I installed Ubuntu 13.10 using the live USB method (created in universal USB creater) and it installed fine as a separate partition. When it started up for the first i noticed that it was running pretty slow e.g. the menus were sluggish. After a serious session of googling, a potential solution was to update/change the display driver but ultimately did not improve the issue . Consequently, i opted to get rid Ubuntu in order to downgrade or find a lighter version of linux altogether and i did this, perhaps mistakenly, by deleting the paritition using XP. Now when i turn on my pc i am greeted with a black screen and a message that says partition missing...After another intense googling session it seems that many solutions begin with the verification of its filesystem name using "f disk -1". However, the command comes up that "-1" is invalid and does not list the filesystem name. After a couple of long nights wielding no results, i thought it was time seek expert help and any help is greatly appreciated

Thanks in advance

Antony

Comment: that would be "fdisk" one word and "-l" with a lowercase "L" as in "lion" so `sudo fdisk -l` is what you enter in, but i'm not sure that would solve things in your case.

Answer (score 0):

1. Insert your Windows XP CD and boot it
2. Open the recovery console
3. Type: fdisk /mbr
4. Reboot

Answer (score 0):

First off the 1 is a lower case L

When you deleted the partition you removed most of the files the machine needs to boot.

You can run an XP disc in recovery mode to reinstall the windows boot loader or, as you are looking to install another linux - do that, it'll reinstall grub while you install and you'll have a bootable machine again.

http://www.wikihow.com/Use-Windows-Recovery-Console-from-XP-CD

try fixboot

You don't say what specs the machine is - just a rather vague and subjective

> i noticed that it was running pretty slow e.g. the menus were sluggish

Try [Xubuntu](http://xubuntu.org/) or [Lubuntu](http://www.lubuntu.net/)

Comment: Thank you so much for answering back. How silly of me to not recognise it as an "L". I do not have an XP cd but if i was to install lubuntu (or linux mint as recomme ded by someone else) would i be able to boot XP like before?

Comment: We've all been there - I fought not being able to find x11 for a while till I realised that it's windows that's not case sensitive ;)